# Displaying remote SMTP TLS certificate information with org.apache.commons.net.smtp

Tags: java, ssl, smtp

I'm using `org.apache.commons.net.smtp.AuthenticatingSMTPClient` to establish connections to SMTP servers. After establishing the initial connection, I use `client.execTLS()` to send `STARTTLS`. I want to get the SMTP TLS certificate information for the certificates used by the remote server. I'm curious if it's possible to do so solely with the API offered by the `org.apache.commons.net.smtp` library.

Alternatively, what options do I have within the Java ecosystem to output the SMTP TLS certificate in a readable format, preferably using the socket already opened by `client.execTLS()`?

Java version: 11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. You can provide your own HostnameVerifier (`null` by default) to the `org.apache.commons.net.smtp.AuthenticatingSMTPClient` object:

```
client.setHostnameVerifier((hostname, session) -> {
  // session.getPeerCertificates();
  return true;
});
```